# Installing pymysql for Python 2.5.1 or lower

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

it doesn't seem like I can find PyMySQL for python 2.5.1 by searching google. Does anyone have external links.

Where do I download/install PyMySQL for python 2.5.1 or lower?

If it's not possible, how do I use MySQL in python 2.5.1?

**Specs: Windows 8 : Python 2.5.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyMySQL is a reasonably new project and was released well after Python 2.5 was already deprecated, so it has never supported it.

You'll probably have better luck with [MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/), which apparently supports Python 2.4 upwards.

Alternatively, given that 2.5 is such an old version of Python, you could consider upgrading to a more modern and supported version.